# Force android app to stay in the orientation it is started in for api level < 18

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I am making an app that needs to stay in the orientation it is started in.
I know how to make it always be in portrait or always in landscape but I need it to be able to start in portrait or start in landscape and stay in the same orientation until it's destroyed.

Currently I'm using

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```

in my [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method but it requires [API level 18](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) or higher and I need my app to work on API level 15 or higher. Can you suggest something?

Comment: when your app starts, use `getRequestedOrientation()` to get the initial orientation. save it in a singleton class and on each activity, access this singleton class to get the orientation and use `setRequestedOrientation()` for setting the initial orientation in all activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example snippet you can use to get the current screen configuration and lock it on all the android devices

It first checks if the screen is in portrait mode if yes then its sets the portrait mode otherwise landscape

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        this.setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else{

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I eventually used your idea but checked `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` because I couldn't find how to check if the orientation is landscape or reverse landscape.

Comment: well `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` returns the rotation with reference to the display's "natural" orientation, i.e. for a tablet it would return `Surface.ROTATION_0` in landscape mode, whereas for a mobile phone it would return the same value for portrait.

Comment: So I need to handle the cases where the rotation is 180 and 270 because it will mean that a reverse orientation is used. I don't have a device to test on which has landscape on rotation 0, but I guess I can just check on those two rotations if `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` returns portrait or landscape and set it to reverse portrait or landscape.